# How can I get a webservice connection to work from Access 2003 runtime install?

Tags: web-services, ms-access

I have an Access 2003 application that communicates with a Webservice to get articles from a central database. It runs fine in a full Access install but when I make runtime install with Package Wizard included in Access 2003 developer extensions, it fails with the error message "429 cannot create an object in the active-x component"
The DLL used for the webservice communication is mssoap30.dll. That dll doesn´t ship with the runtime install and when I try to manually add it to runtime install it is there but when I try to register the DLL it fails with the message:"The register failed reason failed to initiate a DLL" Same result when I put the DLL in the applications folder or in Microsoft shared/Office11. Is there anyone who has made an Access runtime application with web service communication?

Answer (score 2):

If mssoap30.dll is failing to register, that probably means mssoap30.dll itself has dependencies that are missing.

You can download the SOAP Toolkit Installer here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ba611554-5943-444c-b53c-c0a450b7013c&DisplayLang=en

It's only 1.4 MB, and it should fix the problem.  Depending upon what you're using to build your installer, you should be able to embed the SOAP installer and run it during installation (or else just give both files to your users and tell them to install both - that never killed anybody).